# Minus column sums from constant value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this (12x43)

```
Bacteria Sample1 Sample2
A        4.7     4.9
B        8.4     2.9
C        8.9     1.4
```

I'd like to sum all the columns, minus it from 100 and add it as a new row so it looks like this

```
Bacteria Sample1 Sample2
A        4.7     4.9
B        8.4     2.9
C        8.9     1.4
D        78      90.8
```

I have tried this:

```
df[c(1, 100-colSums(df[,2:ncol(df)]) +1)]
```

But it does something extremely odd. The Bacteria column is repeated multiple times across the data frame with random sample columns

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Bacteria = c("A","B",'C'),
                 Sample1 = c(4.7,8.4,8.9),
                 Sample2 = c(4.9,2.9,1.4))
```

Code:

```
df <- add_row(df, df %>%
                summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
                                 ~ 100 - sum(.)))) %>% 
  mutate(Bacteria = ifelse(is.na(Bacteria), "Total", Bacteria))
```

Output:

```
  Bacteria Sample1 Sample2
1        A     4.7     4.9
2        B     8.4     2.9
3        C     8.9     1.4
4    Total    78.0    90.8
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I am getting an error for `summarise`. This is the error `Error in UseMethod("summarise") : 
  no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: What is your dplyr version? @Fiona

Comment: This works fine to me. Please edit your question and provide a data sample with `dput` @Fiona

Comment: I'm an idiot. I hadn't changed `df` to my dataframe name. Thank you so much for the help